# problem accessing namespaced class in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Given a rake task that references both a namespaced and non-namespaced model:

```
namespace :thing do
  task :thingo => :environment do
    Klass.first.some_method
    Namespaced::Klass.first.some_other_method
  end
end
```

Using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.9, and rake 0.9.2, this yields an exception, like so:
`undefined method 'some_other_method' for #<Klass:0x007fcfafbaa6e0>`

### Two things:

1. Why doesn't rails return the proper namespacing in the rake environment (in a debugger session), but it does in a console session?
2. Why does changing the order of reference work?  (That is, if the environment is already calling "Namespaced::Klass" as "Klass", then calling "Klass" should fail with `undefined method 'some_method' for #<Klass:0x007fcfafbaa6e0>` right?

By the way, I've tried `::Namespaced::Klass.first.some_other_method`

If the answer isn't simple, I'll put together a test app - let me know! :-)

Comment: I guess the test app could be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

First, some background on metaphor shear - two different kinds of namespaces:

Although Rake Namepsaces and Ruby Namespaces share the word Namespace, they are separate concepts.  Rake namespaces are just organizing containers for Rake Tasks, not Ruby namespaces/modules.  So code inside your thing:thingo rake task is actually executing at the top-level Ruby namespace.

Second: If Klass is a single class not in a namespace, you can reference it directly.  If the class exists as Foo::Klass then you'll need to use the fully-qualified Foo::Klass reference unless the scope of the reference is already within the Foo namespace.

Because Rake namespaces aren't Ruby modules, you are not in the context of a Ruby namespace within your task.  This is why Klass.some_method works if Klass isn't in a module.

If this doesn't explain the question, please post the class definition for Klass including any module/namespace membership.

Comment: Hi Winfield, sorry for the delayed response.

I understand what you're saying and I apologise that I wasn't clearer.  I'm actually not referring to the rake version of namespacing at all.

I've also since been told that this is not the default behaviour and it's something specific to our app.  I will cut it down and try to find the cause soon.